# Rename Mysql Duplicate Value

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have table " user " with column "username "

because of merged 2 databases we have many duplicate username's , so we want to rename second duplicate value to "sample X2 " the first one shouldn't changed

how can i do this ?

I have searched many times but nothing done :D

Thank you

Comment: A simple Shell/PHP script should be easy to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 UPDATE user
 inner join (SELECT userid, CONCAT(username, ' Copy') as username FROM user
                    GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )t
 on t.userid = user.userid
 SET user.username = t.username
```

if you have duplicate username `'MARK'`

you will get the second one `'MARK Copy'` , change `Copy` by what ever you want.

or use this if you want to update the highest id of every username

```
UPDATE user
inner join (SELECT max(userid) userid , CONCAT(username, ' Copy') as username FROM user
                    GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )t
on t.userid = user.userid
SET user.username = t.username
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5ab3/1)

Comment: Hello , Thanks for Answer but when i try this , I see Error Message :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table SET username = CONCAT(username, ' X2') GROUP BY username HAVING COUN' at line 1

Comment: @user3082118 of course you change the table to your table user ok i edited my answer try it now

Comment: Thanks alot , now i see another Error :  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY username HAVING COUNT(*) > 1' at line 3

Comment: @user3082118 added second query for more options if you want and demo also

Comment: really thanks for quick and fast reply :D , now i see another Error :  #1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: ahh you dont have id in your table ? you have just username ?

Comment: ok , then just replace id by userid ok look edited i replaced them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get id of each second, third, fourth ... records

```
SELECT DISTINCT u2.id
FROM user u1
JOIN user u2 ON (u1.name = u2.name AND u1.name < u2.name)
```

where `user` is your table, `id` is primary key and `name` is username

... and then do update

```
UPDATE user SET name = CONCAT(name, "2") WHERE id IN ( ids )
```

where `ids` is list of id that you get by first step.

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer , but i have over 200000 records and i couldn't write all records id ...