# MySQL Query to rename duplicate column

Tags: mysql

Thanks to this question [Rename Mysql Duplicate Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795891/rename-mysql-duplicate-value) I was able to come up with this queryn to elminate the duplicate rows.

```
UPDATE table1
inner join (SELECT OBJECTID,CONCAT(IDENT,'_1') as IDENT FROM table1
                GROUP BY IDENT HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
        on t.OBJECTID = table1.OBJECTID
SET table1.IDENT = t.IDENT;
```

This works well but I want to only rename the rows where the column IDENT is duplicated and the NAME column is different.  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why isn't `NAME, IDENT` a unique key so you can't have duplicates of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the grouping to be both `NAME` and `IDENT`.

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(objectid) AS max_id, name, CONCAT(ident, '_1') AS new_ident
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY name, ident
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS t ON t.max_id = table1.objectid
SET table1.ident = t.new_ident
```